# Not able to use GPU on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gpu, google-compute-engine

I used Google Cloud Compute Engine and made an Instance with 8vCPUs and 30GB memory and Nvidia V100 GPU, using a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Desktop experience

I checked the display device box as well But When I boot up the system and go to task manager, I don't see the GPU and I can see that the Nvidia GPU V100 exists in the Device Manager but for some reason, it's not doing anything.

I tried installing the Drivers, nothing works, when I try to open the Nvidia Control Panel, I get the error saying "Nvidia Display Settings are not available" "You are not currently using a display attached to an Nvidia GPU". when I right click on desktop and go to the display settings, the options are not available.

I tried uninstalling the GPU and reinstalling it on device manager, but it still doesn't work, I tried reinstalling Nvidia software, but it still doesn't work.

To test the device, I tried playing Apex Legends and It's clear that the GPU is not doing anything because it was taking a few seconds to load EACH FRAME, I don't know what else to do.

All I want is to be able to use the GPU, Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Have you already tried to run any graphics-intensive workloads and see if the GPU is at work?

Comment: Yes I have, I tried to run Apex Legends and It took like 1 second to load each frame.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with GPU's on VM's is that your monitor is not actually connected to the GPU, which would normally occur on a standard machine at home.

The trick is that you need to Build the nbody solution using Visual Studio, after installing CUDA.

This Google GPU guide provides a rough, first step guide on the driver to download...
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#windows-driver-steps

Then, build the solution... 
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html

This is not a bad walkthrough for CUDA install and build, https://medium.com/@nicerova/cuda-on-windows-the-definitive-guide-b4130b9fc419